# Redirect ?q=user/register to the base url using .htaccess in Drupal 7

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, redirect

In our drupal 7 site we were not providing user registration and redirect the the user/register page to the base url using .htaccess.

```
#Custom redirects

RewriteRule ^user/register$ http://%{HTTP_HOST} [R=301,L]

#End Custom redirects
```

It is working and now I need to redirect '?q=user/register' also to that base url. When I tried with

```
  RewriteRule ^?q=user/register$ http://%{HTTP_HOST} [R=301,L]
```

but it was not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URI `/?q=user/register` is already the base, it's just got a query string, the URI is still `/`. If your goal is to remove the query string, then you need to match against the query string first, which you can't do in a `RewriteRule`. You need to match against `%{QUERY_STRING}` in a `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} q=user/register
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/? [R=301,L]
```

Note that the target has a `?` at the end, this will *remove* the query strring so **q=user/register** won't get automatically appended.

Comment: Hello Jon Lin, Sorry to bother you again. But actually I want to search for the string q=user/register. What happened is if someone try with the url like http://www.mysite.com/?q=/user/register or http://www.mysite.com/?q=//user/register the above logic won't work. So I think we need to search for q=user/register and need to remove the '/' in the url. Can you please help me for achieving this? Please reply as soon as possible, because I need this urgent.

Comment: @Rajeesh Change `q=user/register` to `q=/*user/register`

Comment: Thanks John for saving my head again. I don't know what to say. You are the man.. It works like a charm. :)

Comment: Hi John Lin, this time I have some other issues. I want to redirect from this url http://www.mysite.com/propertydetailspage.php?id=MjMy to this url http://www.mysite.com/view-properties. But sometimes the first url is may be http://www.mysite.com/propertydetailspage.php?pgSize=30&pgNo=1&city_id=27 and the values of pgSize and pgNo will be changing. Mainly  I need to catch propertydetailspage.php in the first url and redirect it into http://www.mysite.com/view-properties. I hope now you can understand my problem. Please share your thoughts as soon as possible. Thanks in advance.